# `rgl` package does not show 3d plots of anything

Tags: r, plot, 3d, rgl

When i want to view the graphics, i got a clean window, do you know why?

```
> library(vegan3d)
Loading required package: vegan
Loading required package: permute
Loading required package: lattice
This is vegan 2.6-2
> library(scatterplot3d)
> library(plot3D)
> library(rgl)
 This build of rgl does not include OpenGL functions.  Use
 rglwidget() to display results, e.g. via options(rgl.printRglwidget = TRUE).
> options(rgl.printRglwidget = TRUE)  #[all of this, i mean is correct]
```

but, when i run the following:

```
> plot3d(x = o$NMDS1, y = o$NMDS2, z = o$NMDS3)
it delivers nothing
```

[image]

Comment: What happens when you run `rglwidget()` explicitly, instead of relying on auto-printing?

Comment: And what version of `rgl` are you using?

Comment: > library(rgl)
This build of rgl does not include OpenGL functions.  Use
 rglwidget() to display results, e.g. via options(rgl.printRglwidget = TRUE).
im working with R 4.2.0 (2022-04-22) -- "Vigorous Calisthenics" and my version of rgl is 0.109.2 and y type: options(rgl.printRglwidget = TRUE) but is still not working :(

Comment: I suspect this is an RStudio issue.  If you run R outside of RStudio, it should open a web browser when you run `rglwidget()`.  Does that display anything?

Comment: And where did you get the build that doesn't include OpenGL?  I think the CRAN binaries all do.

Comment: If you're a Linux user, this can simply due to missing system librairies (typically, something like `glu-devel` might be missing). In this case, install these system librairies, and then re-install you R package `rgl`.